# Access 2013 How to view Relationships pictograms?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, relationships

I use Access 2013 and it looks so that this is the only version which doesn´t shows the relationships pictograms (infinite symbol and 1).
I assume there is a way to activate it thus I can see it in the relationship designer?

Comment: I have to think field on the one side not set as PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only see these when enforcing referential integrity.

As soon as you enforce referential integrity, they will be visible.

Comment: The clicks for enforcing referential integrity in 
pictures https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYf9OZQH4hQ